# How to know when Spotify access token is expired and know when it is should be refreshing

Tags: python, spotipy

I am running a Python script in the background utilizing the Spotipy module. Sometimes the script stop doing what it is suppose to do and I am assuming it is because it doesn't refresh the token in time. Is there a method where I can check programmatically within the script that the token is expired and prompt it to automatically refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can add a simple conditional statement to your script to see if the token expired and refresh it if so with [is_token_expired](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.1/?highlight=refresh%20token#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth.is_token_expired) and [refresh_access_token](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.1/?highlight=refresh%20token#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth.refresh_access_token) or you can add try except logic where the exception spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError is handled by refreshing the token and continuing.

Comment: yeah, and you could even create a decorator which always does the token expired check before running the function it decorates